# qendian.h:219: error: undefined reference to `char* qbswap<char*>(char*)'

Tags: c++, qt

I encountered this error while trying to use qFromBigEndian.

```
QByteArray message = ...;
qDebug() << qFromBigEndian(message.data());
```

The error is:

```
qendian.h:219: error: undefined reference to `char* qbswap<char*>(char*)'
```

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

From reading https://www.qtcentre.org/threads/18728-qFromBigEndian(-)-not-found, it seems I need to specify the type explicitly.

```
qDebug() << qFromBigEndian<uint32_t>(message.data());
```

instead of

```
qDebug() << qFromBigEndian(message.data());
```